# React Fabric UI remove the Pivot Item

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I am using Pivot component in Office Fabric UI, I need to remove PivotItem for some views. Is there any possible way?

etc. I need to remove 'Insert' Pivot with using isComposeMode() in below

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Label } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Label";
import { Pivot, PivotItem } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Pivot";
import InsertView from "./InsertView";

export interface PivotProps {}

export interface PivotState {}

class MainNav extends React.Component<PivotProps, PivotState> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Pivot>
          <PivotItem headerText="Insert">
            <InsertView />
          </PivotItem>
          <PivotItem headerText="Review">
            <Label>Review</Label>
          </PivotItem>
          <PivotItem headerText="Settings">
            <Label>Settings</Label>
          </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
      </div>
    );
  }

  isComposeMode = (): boolean => {
    if (Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm != undefined) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
}

export default MainNav;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array approach above is great, but you can conditionally include items in the array and then filter out “falsy” values using the `.filter(Boolean)` method. This allows you to include the item only if the condition is true.

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Pivot, PivotItem, InsertView, Label } from '.'

export interface PivotProps {
    isComposeMode: boolean
}

class MainNav extends React.Component<PivotProps> {
    public render() {
        const items = [
            this.props.isComposeMode && <PivotItem key="insert" headerText="Insert"><InsertView /></PivotItem>,
            <PivotItem key="review"headerText="Review"><Label>Review</Label></PivotItem>,
            <PivotItem key="settings" headerText="Settings"><Label>Settings</Label></PivotItem>
        ].filter(Boolean)

        return (
            <Pivot>
                {items}
            </Pivot>
        )
    }
}
```

You should also derive `isComposeMode` in a parent component and pass it in as a prop. This will make your component more reusable and won’t tie it to your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can push the required items to an array based on your condition. Hope this can help you.

```
render(){ 
  let pivotItems=[
    <PivotItem headerText="Insert">
            <InsertView />
    </PivotItem>,
    <PivotItem headerText="Review">
            <Label>Review</Label>
    </PivotItem>,
];

if(addLastPivot){
   pivotItems.push( 
      <PivotItem headerText="Settings">
            <Label>Settings</Label>
      </PivotItem>
   );
}

return (
      <div>
        <Pivot>
          {pivotItems}
        </Pivot>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: `pivotItems.push()` will add the item to the end of the array. Based on the original question, you would need to use `pivotItems.unshift()` if you want to add it to the beginning of the array.